# Формат Url для пагинации

Tags: joomla, pagination

Задача в том чтобы изменить формат url c `/vse.html?page=4` на `vse.html/page/4`
система Joomla 1.5
долго ковырялся в файлах `/libraries/joomla/html/pagination.php`  и `/includes/router.php`  нашел что откуда берется, и что куда передается, но сменить принцип отображения так и не смог , я подозреваю что гет параметр формируется где то глубоко в ядре джумлы, буду очень признателен за совет.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще один вариант - **через .htaccess**
Правда нужно удостовериться, чтобы внесенные изменения не конфликтовали с ЧПУ Joomla.

Если я не ошибаюсь, то должно быть что-то вроде:

```
RewriteRule ^vse/page/([0-9]+)/?$ vse.php?page=$1 [L]
```

[Посмотрите здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666140/htaccess-rewriting-php-pagination), похожая ситуация

Answer (score 0):

Статья по включению SEF (ЧПУ) в Joomla 1.5

http://palpalych.ru/blog/24-rasshireniya/156-vkljuchenie-standartnogo-sef-v-joomla-15xx.html

Comment: эти настройки включены, кроме того насколько я понимаю они не относятся к  настройкам пагинации.